# Why a ruby command runs even if a user don't activate the script yet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a Ruby user, trying to make a web service that receives user's active request. I made a button, of which class is a "btn-send-alert". Then after the html code, I put a script function.

```
<div class="page-title">
     <button class="btn-send-alert"  style="background-color: transparent;">Help Request</button>
     <p>Hello</p><br>
  </div>
```

........

```
<script>

    $(".btn-send-alert").click(function(){
      alert('hello!');
      <% Smalier.class_alert(@lesson,current_user).deliver_now %>
    });

</script>
```

The problem is, the ruby code just start on its own even before I click this button.

And if I click this button, no email is delivered any longer.

Maybe in some point, I think I'm seriously wrong but I can't find where it is. Is there way that I can make this function work correctly?

Looking forward to seeing the response!

Best

Thanks to Rich, I am now able to write a code that works fine! The below code is that code.

```
  <%= content_tag :div, class: "page-title" do %>
       <%= button_to "Help Request",  support_path, method: :get, remote: true, class:"btn btn-danger", params: { lesson_id: @lesson.id, user_id: current_user.id} %>
       <%= content_tag :i, "wow!" %>
```

////

def support

```
@lesson = Lesson.find_by(:id => params[:lesson_id])
current_user = User.find_by(:id => params[:user_id])
```

mailer.class_alert(@lesson,current_user).deliver_now

end

Above code runs well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm a Ruby user

Welcome to Rails!!

---

**Stateless**

Firstly, you need to understand that Rails applications - by virtue of running through [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) - are [*stateless*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol), meaning that "state" such as `User` or `Account` have to be re-established with each new action.

In short, this means that invoking actions/commands on your system have to be done through *ajax* or another form of server-connectivity.

Many native developers (native apps are *stateful*) don't understand how Rails / web apps are able to retain "state", and thus make a bunch of mistakes with their code.

> receives user's active request

Even if you understand how to set up authentication inside a Rails app, it's important to understand the virtues of it being *stateless*... EG the above line means you have to have a user *signed in* and authenticated before you can send the request.

This forms one part of your problem (I'll explain in a second)

---

**ERB**

Secondly, the other problem you have is with the [**ERB** nature of Rails](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/better_views/erb_and_haml.html).

> the ruby code just start on its own even before I click this button.

This happens because you're including pure Ruby code in your front-end scripts. This means that whenever these scripts are loaded (triggered), they will fire.

The bottom line here is you need to put this script on your server. Otherwise it will just run...

---

## Fixes

**1. ERB**

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "page-title" do %>
     <%= button_tag "Help Request", class:"btn-send-alert" %>
     <%= content_tag :p, "Hello %>
<% end %>
```

You'll thank me in 1+ months.

[Convention over Configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) means you use as many of the [Rails helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html) as you can. You don't need to go stupid with it, but the more "conventional" your code is, the better it will be for future developers to improve it.

- Another tip - *only use HTML for formatting*; CSS for styling. Don't use `<br>` unless you *actually* want to break a line.
- Another tip - *never use inline styling* - Rails has an adequate [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) into which you should put all your CSS

--

**2. Ajax**

Secondly, your use of Javascript is incorrect.

More specifically, you're calling a server-based function inside front-end views. To explain this a little more, I'll show you the famed MVC image I post on here a lot:

[image]

This is how Rails works ([MVC - **M**odel **V**iew **C**ontroller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)) - this means that whenever you deal with your application, you have to accommodate a layer of abstraction between the user & your app -- the *browser*.

By its nature, the browser is not stateful - it stores session cookies which you have to authenticate on the server. You cannot call "server" code in the front-end HTML/JS.

This is why your Ruby code is firing without any interaction, although I'm not sure how it's able to fire in the asset pipeline.

If you want to make it work properly, you'll need to create a *controller action* to invoke the mailer send function, which you'll be able to do using the following setup:

```
#config/routes.rb
get :support, to: "application#support", as: :support -> url.com/support

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   respond_to :js, only: :support
   def support
      Smalier.class_alert(@lesson.current_user).deliver_now
   end
end

#app/views/controller/view.html.erb
<%= content_tag :div, class: "page-title" do %>
     <%= button_to "Help Request",  support_path, method: :get, class:"btn-send-alert" %>
     <%= content_tag :p, "Hello" %>
<% end %>

#app/views/application/support.js.erb
alert ("Hello");
```

Comment: Thanks Rich!. Here I now have two issue. One is, it says "template missing". [ This is address where I see this log http://localhost:3000/support?]. Also the support method has two variables ( @lesson, current_user). How can I get two inputs(@lesson, current_user) in your example? (: I do want to study!

Answer (score 1):

Each and every ruby code snippet embedded in ERB runs on server, in order to assemble a valid HTML or Javascript script for browsers to render.

Browsers don't understand ruby script at all, all they can understand is HTML and Javascript.

In your case (I'm supposing you're using rails since you tagged your question with `ruby-on-rails`), emails are delivered when rails engine is assembling HTML's.

If you want the emails being sent after the users click that button, the correct way is:

1. Define an action method in some controller, give it an URL (i.e. add a route in `config/routes.rb`), send email in that action.
2. When the button on the page is clicked, send an AJAX request to that URL.